# Mouser over handler across all JavaFX Nodes

Tags: java, javafx-2

Let's say I have a JavaFX 2.x Pane with lots of Nodes, including nested ones, strewn about it positioned absolutely.

I want to know anytime the mouse goes over any Node and take some action based on what Node it is. Is there some way to do that over all the Nodes, or do I have to add a mouse listener on every single Node individually?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JavaFX, but I'd assume you add it to their shared parent, in this case the `Pane`.

Comment: @taotree There is a JavaFX platform feature request for this: [FX should provide a Parent.pick() routine](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20184), unfortunately not scheduled until after the Java 8 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik this is not possible with a single API call in JavaFX 2.2. Now what you can do, if you don't mind the extra work, is:

1) track the mouse position with an AWTEventListener (which may still be bugged on OSX)
2) start with your scene's root, list all the children find the one that has boundsInParent containing the mouse position. If there is no such node, you're done.
3) If that node is a parent, convert the mouse position to the node by removing the node's x and y position from the coordinate and repeat with #2. Otherwise, you're done.

Not pretty, and not particularly fast, but if you need the function for something like debugging or maybe an online help it might do. I'm not aware of any better way right now.

Comment: Thanks for the possible workaround. Adding a listener to every node is probably just as kludgy, though not sure which would perform worse. I think jewelsea had the short answer: no, but there is a feature request for it. So, for now, workaround. Thanks!